# Centos 7 Standard output (>) with same position as in the Original file

Tags: sh

I am looking for a command to copy a text into another file but the matched text needs to be in exact position as in the original file. Can someone assist me?
For example:

```
$ cat file1
one
two
three
four
five
three

$ grep three file1 > newfile1
```

The output from above command will always show `three` at the first and second row only. Is there a way I can get the matched text in `newfile1` at third and sixth row (same as in the original file)?

Comment: What should appear in the lines that don't match?  (Just empty lines?)  Do you have any particular preferences on tools you'd like to use?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking of it as a search for the string `three`, let's reframe the problem: print every line, but erase ones that don't contain `three`.

```
$ awk '!/three/{$0=""} {print}' file1


three


three
```

`!/three/` matches lines that don't contain the search string, `{$0=""}` clears them, and the unconditional `{print}` prints every single line.

A shorter (but more cryptic) way to write it is to replace `{print}` with `1`, which does the same thing.

```
$ awk '!/three/{$0=""} 1' file1
```